# Сделать commit из TeamExplorer на github

Tags: visual-studio, github, explorer, team

Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так. Почему нет Commit? Все перепробовал. Сильно туплю, новичок. В какой то момент что-то пошло не так и вот  результат. Перегуглил все, не нашел свою проблему. Видимо не знаю просто как вопрос поставить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проект был уже залит ранее на гитхаб. Случайно удалил потом и создал заново с тем же именем. Подрубаюсь, все ок. Думал решением будет снять с контроля решение и поставить заново, но не понял как сделать это.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решен. В новой студии они интерфейс перелопатили и теперь, чтобы сделать коммит, надо идти на вкладку Git Changes и в выпадайке Commit выбирать из списка Commit and Push.